# wsimport creates classes that produce a wsdl that is different from the source wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I'm trying to use wsimport (or more accurately I'm using the eclipse wizard that uses wsimport) to generate new server side classes for a webservice. The source WSDL comes from the current implementation via the ../ServiceName?wsdl URL.

My problem is that when I publish the new classes and navigate to the new ?wsdl URL the results WSDL is different than the original. This seems to be a cause of errors when the existing clients try to use the new version of the service. Here is a subsection of the WSDL with an example of a difference that seems to cause a problem with the clients:

Original:

```
<wsdl:message name="executeResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:ServiceNameResult" name="ServiceNameResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="executeRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="impl:executeRequest" name="executeRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ServiceName">
  <wsdl:operation name="execute" parameterOrder="executeRequest">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:executeRequest" name="executeRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="impl:executeResponse" name="executeResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

New:

```
<wsdl:message name="executeResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ServiceNameResult" name="ServiceNameResult">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="execute">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:executeRequest" name="executeRequest">
  </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ServiceName">
    <wsdl:operation name="execute">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:execute" name="execute">
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:executeResponse" name="executeResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

The change is in the portType input message. It gets renamed from "executeRequest" to simply "execute".

I can't figure out why this would change or how to correct it in the java classes. All the annotations seem correct.

Comment: Are you using Apache Axis2, Apache Axis or Apache CXF within your Eclipse to generate Java classes from WSDL?

Comment: Apache CXF I believe. But I'm not entirely sure. When I publish them it says it's a CXF Webservice. I'm publishing to Liberty Profile.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I'm using IBM WebSphere JAX-WS.

Comment: No idea what implementation IBM uses for JAX-WS. Clearly one needs to identify what WSDL version (1.1 or 2.0) and how it interprets the WSDL to Java Beans.

Comment: You will need to subclass `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration` and override `getInputMessageName` method to append the `QName` with `"Request"`. Then, you will have to configure CXF to point the service configuration to your subclass.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi What about using something like this?: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Also, do you want to post your above comment as an Answer? I think that's a better solution than implementing an interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the missing "Request" suffix is a feature and not a bug of CXF. What I need to do is either update my clients or implement serverside interceptors:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

This:

You will need to subclass org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration and override getInputMessageName method to append the QName with "Request". Then, you will have to configure CXF to point the service configuration to your subclass

Also seems like a good solution if I can figure out how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818072/subclassing-defaultserviceconfiguration